# Term for this kind of door

Tags: word-request, image-identification

I have searched on the internet but I can't figure out if there is a specific term for a kind of door.
It's about doors that open downwards much like an oven, but I've seen this kind of door on a sideboard (like the one showed in the image). Likewise, I have seen pictures of cabinets with doors that open upwards.
I looked up a bit and these kinds of doors have some special mechanism (or hinges) called lid stay?

[image: cabinet with a horizontal door that has opens from the top]

I'm not too good when it comes to hardware stuff so I hope I explained well...I heard someone said "folding doors" but I'm not sure that is the correct them as well because folding doors are another kind. I know of swing doors, sliding doors, but the ones that I tried to explain I do not know what term they might have.

Comment: I guess it's a flap door.

Comment: Hmm, flap doors make me think of the ones used for pets, but I did search to see images and indeed the ones like in my example show up.

Comment: From these suggestions, I searched again and remembered another term and I'm not sure just how much it is used. I found tilt door (or tilt-out). Is it a common term? 
Also I did look up [here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/flap-door) here for the definition and it would seem that it matches the description of this particular door that I want to know about.

Answer (score 3):

This kind of drawer or cabinet door is often called a **tip-out** drawer or tip-out door in the US. Some people will refer to them as **tilt-out**.

Here's a picture (with a brand-name removed) from a popular US woodworking site.

[image: Tilt-Out Door]

Comment: But it's not a drawer, it's a door. This is a [tip-out drawer](http://assets.rockler.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/720x720/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/6/5/6572-11-1000.jpg)

Comment: It's a tip-out in either case.It requires some form of tip-out hinge.

Comment: Tilt-out is a good description as well - I just thought referring to it as a drawer might be confusing.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone for the examples! I shall talk about these two terms "tilt-out" and "tip-out" with a person I'm working with. We have to translate some product descriptions and these terms would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Doors tend to be described by the action you take to open them. Your example is a "drop-down" door. There may be other names for a particular style of door, but if you need the most generic way to explain it, describing the way it opens is a good choice. Here are some examples - if you search for images using these terms, you should find more.

[Drop-down Door Desk Hutch](http://www.ana-white.com/2015/05/DIY_furniture/drop-down-door-hutch-desk)

[image: Cabinet with a door that folds down into a desk surface]

Lift-up door:

[image: two wall cabinets with doors that open by lifting]

Roll-up door:

[image: door on rails that rolls up at the top]

Sliding door:
[image: cabinet with a door that slides left or right to open]

Comment: Thank you for all the examples! I had to search for a more general term because I have to translate some descriptions for products and in the descriptions in my language, most of the times it does not state whether the doors open downwards or upwards because we have secondary pictures for the product and the direction of the opened door is displayed in them.